# Bypass self signed certificate in IBM MobileFirst Platform Android

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, self-signed

I need to access a https url with self signed certificate in my development mode. So, I want to bypass the self signed cert in android which is generated by IBM MobileFirst Platform. I have try to generate a debug apk and also installed the cert into my device, none of them work.

I was still getting

> "Failed to validate the certificate chain, error:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found."

I not able to modify CordovaWebViewClient.java since cordova plugin was generated by IBM mobile platform.

Does anybody know the solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug APKs usually ignore certificate errors. I am not sure whats going wrong there. So if we concentrate on the error itself, it mainly means you don't have the self signed certificate added to the trust store of the device.

1. When you open the IBM MobileFirst Platform console in browser (https://host:port/worklightconsole or https://host:port/mfpconsole) do you see the warning saying the host is not trusted ? If yes, this means you don't have right certificate added to the device.
2. Check which certificate you added to the device 
   To get the right certificate, easiest option is to use openssl command.
   Run this command replacing host with your host and port with https port: 
   *openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host:port*.
   This will show both the server certificate and CA certificate. Since yours is a self signed certificate, you will see only that. So copy the content starting from *-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----* till *-----END CERTIFICATE-----* and put it in a file, say mycert.crt and try to add this certificate to your device trust store. Use the test mentioned in (1) again to see if its working before trying it through the app itself.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, finally get it work by follow your step 2 , copy the cert content and import into my device! Thanks!